# Qt Error: Signal QDeclarativeEngine::quit() emitted, but no receivers connected to handle it

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am very new to Qt so that some Qt issues I can't figure out. I will really appreciate if somebody can help me.

I am trying to get rid of application window's frame and create an exit button in qml in order to exit the application. Hence, I make a program as following:

main.cpp

```
 #include <QtGui/QApplication>
 #include <QDeclarativeContext>
 #include <QObject>
 #include "qmlapplicationviewer.h"
 #include "myclass.h"
 #include "mainwindow.h"

 Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     MyClass myClass;
     MainWindow window;

     window.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myObject", &myClass);
     window.show();

     return app.exec();
 }
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
 #include "mainwindow.h"

 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QDeclarativeView(parent)
 {
     // No window decorations
     setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

     // Set QML file
     setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("qml/Test2/main.qml"));
 }

 // Destructor.
 MainWindow::~MainWindow()
 {
 }
```

myclass.cpp

```
 #include <QDeclarativeEngine>
 #include <QDeclarativeComponent>
 #include <QDeclarativeContext>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "myclass.h"

 MyClass::MyClass()
 {
     click_count = 0;
 }

 int MyClass::click_function(void)
 {
     click_count++;
     fprintf(stderr, "CLICK COUNT in CPP: %d\n", click_count);
     return click_count;
 }
```

qml

```
 MouseArea {
     id: mouse_exit
     anchors.fill: parent
     onClicked: {
         console.log("Click on exit button: ")
         console.log("click count: ", myObject.click_function())
         Qt.quit();
     }
 }
```

It compiles successfully, however, whenever I click on the exit button, the Qt error "**Signal QDeclarativeEngine::quit() emitted, but no receivers connected to handle it**" occurs. Based on my searching online for this issue, it seems like I have to connect the QDeclarativeEngine::quit() signal to the QApplication::quit() slot. But there isn't too much information for using connect() function. I tried many ways to use connect(), but I still couldn't know how to use it for this case.

Can anybody help me solve this problem? I will really really appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
connect(sender, SIGNAL(signalName(args)), receiver, SLOT(slotName(args)));
```

You can put it in your MyClass constructor:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(quit()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
```

Or in the main function, since `connect()` is a static function, as Slavic81 pointed out in the comment below.

Note that qApp is a macro for the global application.

Comment: It can actually go in the main function. It's a static function. You just need to explicitly state the class when you use it outside of a QObject. Like so: `QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(quit()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));`

Comment: Yeah, it works. Though, obviously you can't use `this` in main. That should have been `window.rootContext()->engine()`, but it's too late for me to edit my comment.

Comment: @Slavik81 Perfect!!! Thank you very much for pointing out window.rootContext()->engine(). The wrong sender in my connect() is the reason of the above problem, since I use &window as the sender. Now, using "QObject::connect(window.rootContext()->engine(), SIGNAL(quit()), QCoreApplication::instance(), SLOT(quit()));" works perfectly. Thank you so much. I appreciate!